Create a dataframe with pandas correctly from a CSV file
I am using jupyter notebook to practice Python skills. And I am having some problems creating a dataframe correctly using some of Kaggle datasets. I am not being able to know exactly how to do it. Here is the link to kaggle to find them
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows/data
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud
If someone could please point me into the right direction I would be greatful

What did you try? did you download the dataset? did you use pd.read_csv(...) ?

have you managed to downloaded the dataset ?

This question is not very clear. Please write a more clear question to get the answer.
However, to get you started, here are some tips.
Jupyter Notebook Solution:
If you are using Kaggle data and using Jupyter Notebook to write your code, then you have to do a few things.
First off, you need to add Kaggle API to your Jupyter Notebook.
If you google, you will find the steps.
Step 1: Install the Kaggle API. ...
Step 2: Create a Kaggle Account. ...
Step 3: Generate an API Token. ...
Step 4: Move the API Token to Jupyter Notebook. ...
Step 5: Download the Kaggle Dataset. ...
Step 6: Unzip the Dataset. ...
Step 7: Load the Dataset into Jupyter Notebook.
If you still have challenges, please read through this article on Kaggle.
https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api
Kaggle Solution:
If you are using Kaggle itself, you can just go to the dataset and click on New Notebook. Then use the pd.read_csv file as shown below.
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows
df = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/netflix-shows/netflix_titles.csv")

I am downloading it as CSV, and when I create the dataframe is created incorrectly, in one case it creates only one column and in the other case it creates several columns but all the info of the columns are in the first one.
I tried installing Kaggle API but is not possible

Please share your code so we can review and comment. Without seeing your code, we don't know what the issue is
